# Delphi How to use types from other forms?

Tags: delphi

Sorry this is a very newbie question.

We have this massive application I am doing maintenance on.  It has 5 different forms.  We put our global variables in one unit (uGlobal).  But i can't seem to access it from the data unit (uData).

I have this:

```
Unit uGlobal
type
TmyType: (alpha, beta);
...

Unit uGlobal

Stuff:  TmyType  <- error, undeclared indentifier
```

When i try to put uGlobal in the uses section of uData, it complains of a circular reference.  So, kinda clueless here.  They are both in the same project.  This is using BDS 2006.

Comment: +1 very newbie yes, but everybody has to learn this sometime.

Comment: You have little mistake in your code sample that confuses the issue a bit. You've named both units 'uGlobal'. Please edit your question to clarify.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a circular reference because you have things in `uGlobal` that want to make use of things in `uData` and vice-versa. Circular references are a big concern in large projects because they greatly increase complexity - if you have circular dependencies, it becomes more like one BIGGER unit. I suspect you have a long way to go before your project can be considered large, let alone "massive". ;)

You have 2 possible solutions:

- Go with the circular dependency, making one dependency *weak*, and the other *strong*.
- Apply a little redesign to eliminate the problem alogether. (Break things into smaller chunks.)

### Keeping the circular dependency

David has already given the answer: At least one of the units must use the other from the implementation section.

- A uses B uses A is absolutely not allowed, but you can think of the interface and implementation sections as being *almost like* separate units themselves (with a bunch of special referencing rules).
- So ask yourself what does each *sub-unit* need?
- If for example:

  - You declared a type in `uData interface` and referenced that in `uGlobal interface`, then the interface of `uGlobal` **needs** `uData` and will need a corresponding uses clause.
  - If there's a type in `uData implementation` that's referenced in anywhere `uGlobal`, then that declaration in `uData implementation` must be moved to the interface section.
  - If there's a type in `uGlobal interface` must it's only referenced from the implementation section of `uData` then that uses clause will be fine in the implementation section.
- If you have the unfortunate situation that types in both interface sections reference types in the other interface section, then you **have to** to modularise a little more by applying the technique to ***Remove Circular Dependency***.

### Remove Circular Dependency

Removing the circular dependency requires breaking your units down into smaller ones that are more manageable. To do this, you **must** understand the ***dependencies*** between each of the *things* in your application.
For example:

- Suppose `uGlobal` declares A and C
- A depends on C, but C doesn't need A
- Suppose also that `uData` declares B which needs C
- But it turns out that A also needs B
- This is why you have the circular dependency

All you have to do in this case is declare a new unit at move C in there.

- Then both `uGlobal` and `uData` will use `uNewUnit`
- But neither will need the other
- And your circular dependency will be removed entirely.

### Disclaimer

I am not in any way advocating your approach with uGlobal. In fact it is a very bad idea and will bite you big time on 2 fronts when your projects starts to get large. Unfortunately the explanation is a mammoth answer in itself.

- Use of global variables at all is dangerous and to be avoided.
- Use of 'big dumping units' like uGlobal and uData is also dangerous, and you've only just satrted to experience their problems.

Answer (score 4):

Use the second 'uses', the one in the 'implementation' section

```
unit uData;

uses SysUtils, etc;

type
  etc;

implementation

uses uGlobal;

// here you can reference things in uGlobal
```

Comment: There is a reference to uGlobal in implementation already.  Is there a way to make the MyType public somehow?

Answer (score 2):

Generally David Zimmerman's answer is the way to go, but in your case (according to your response to David's answer), you need TMyType in the interface section of uGlobal unit; therefore adding uData to uses clause of the implementation section won't help.

Seems it is time for refactoring; you should consider moving TMyType or Stuff into a third unit, so that both uData and uGlobal can reference to it.