# A list class to store enums?

Tags: delphi, list, enums, delphi-2007

What List type I should use to store enum values? I have tried with TObjectList, I cast to TObject to Add the value, but can't cast it back to enum when reading from the list.

What list do you use to store enums?

Comment: Casting back from TObject should work, show your code.

Comment: You probably have to cast twice: `TYourEnum(Integer(obj))`.

Comment: @Ulrich - no, you don't. See the *working* example I posted for my answer.

Comment: @Cosmin: You're right: `al := TAlign(obj);`compiles with `var obj: TObject; al: TAlign;`. Must have mixed that up with something else.

Comment: Don't use TObjectList. That class carries the notion of "ownership" of the objects it contains, but you can't own enum values. If your list doesn't know that what it contains aren't objects, it might try to free them when they're removed. Instead, use plain old TList.

Comment: A `set of <enumtype>` gives a typesafe enum list type

Comment: @mjn, a `set of <enumtype>` gives a set, not a list. There's no concept of "order" in a set and you can't add the same value twice.

Answer (score 6):

Casting enums to `Pointer` or `TObject` and back works just fine. If your Delphi version supports generics use Tim's suggestion, it's better. Alternatively you can use an dynamic array (`array of TTestEnum`) or create a wrapper class around the dynamic array - that's how generic lists are implemented in Delphi versions capable of generics.

Here's a quick console demo, using `TList`, not `TObjectList` because `TList` makes fewer assumptions about the items it holds.

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses SysUtils, Classes;

type TTestEnum = (enum1, enum2, enum3, enum4);

var L: TList;
    i: Integer;
    E: TTestEnum;

begin
  L := TList.Create;
  try
    L.Add(Pointer(enum1));
    L.Add(Pointer(enum2));
    L.Add(Pointer(enum3));
    L.Add(Pointer(enum4));
    for i:=0 to L.Count-1 do
    begin
      E := TTestEnum(L[i]);
      case E of
        enum1: WriteLn('enum1');
        enum2: WriteLn('enum2');
        enum3: WriteLn('enum3');
        enum4: WriteLn('enum4');
      end;
    end;
  finally L.Free;
  end;
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Comment: A sanity check to verify that the value is of the enum type would be a plus - as the list is not typesafe, any enum pointer could be added but since there is no type info in an Pointer, the original type can not be determined when reading the values back.

Comment: This also works where the emunerations are of different types, but loses the type information. If you went List.Add(FormState); List.Add(ModalResult); that would work but good luck getting them back out in any meaningful way.

Comment: @moz, @mjn: when you work with such basic collections, you obviously don't get any type safety. That's why I recommend a generic collection if available, or a dynamic array, or a class wrapping a dynamic array. I only wanted to prove casting an enum to a pointer and back is perfectly possible, I'm not saying this is the best way to do it.

Comment: definitely. I just thought it was worth pointing out that it's not just the detailed type you lose.

Answer (score 5):

Could you not just use Generics for this?

```
TList<TEnumName>;
```

Comment: Not in Delphi 2007 (as mentioned in the tags).

Comment: Undid incorrect downvote. I missed the fact that the question when Tim answered it may not have contained the Delphi version, as it was added via an edit at about the time Tim made his post.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797368/delphi-tlist-of-records/5797696#5797696) may help. It's about storing records in a TList by creating a descendant to avoid all the typecasting. Note that you won't need to worry about allocating/freeing memory for the enum values, as they're simple ordinal types that fit in the space of a pointer.

Note that you have to typecast to `Pointer` when `Add`ing to the list, and may have to typecast as `YourEnum(Integer(List[Index])) when reading back. However, the code I linked to shows how to handle both in the descendant class so it's only done once each way, and that's buried in the class implementation.