# Delphi Generics method

Tags: delphi, generics

I am using generics to define a list of objects that themselves hold generic lists. I have written a method for retrieving the aggregate of each of these lists using specific methods that basically do the same thing. Below is the structure:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
 System.Generics.Collections;

type
  TListType=(ltSType,ltFType);

  TMyList<T> = class(TList<T>)
   {Do some stuff in here to help load lists etc}
  end;

  TListObject=class(TObject)
  private
    FSList:TMyList<string>;
    FIList:TMyList<integer>;
    function GetSList: TMyList<string>;
    function GetIList: TMyList<integer>;
  public
    property MySList:TMyList<string> read GetSList;
    property MyIList:TMyList<integer> read GetIList;
    constructor create;
  end;

  TListOfObject<T:TListObject> = class(TObjectList<T>)
  public
    Function AggrSList:TMyList<string>;
    Function AggrIList:TMyList<integer>;
  end;

implementation

{ TListObject }

constructor TListObject.create;
begin
  FSList:=TMyList<string>.create;
  FIList:=TMyList<integer>.create;
end;

function TListObject.GetIList: TMyList<integer>;
begin
  result:=FIlist;
end;

function TListObject.GetSList: TMyList<string>;
begin
  result:=FSList;
end;


{ TListOfObject<T> }

function TListOfObject<T>.AggrIList: TMyList<integer>;
var
  i,j:integer;

begin
  result:=TMyList<integer>.create;
  for I := 0 to count-1 do
    for j := 0 to items[i].MyIList.Count-1 do
      result.Add(items[i].MyIList[j]);
end;

function TListOfObject<T>.AggrSList: TMyList<string>;
var
  i,j:integer;
begin
  result:=TMyList<string>.create;
  for I := 0 to count-1 do
    for j := 0 to items[i].MySList.Count-1 do
      result.Add(items[i].MySList[j]);
end;

end.
```

I am still fairly new to generics but feel that the aggregate methods AggrIList and AggrSlist could be written using generics that uses a single method to extract the data then is cast at the result.

Is this possible and how would I approach this? I plan to do some more advanced functions that would benefit from this approach as well.

Comment: Check documentation ... http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE7/en/Generics_Collections_TObjectList_(Delphi).  
You can use TObjectList<TNewObject>, you don't need to make it so difficult as in your example.  
Or you can use simple TList with records ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797368/delphi-tlist-of-records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use (pseudocode):

```
TNestedList<T> = class(TList<TList<T>>)
  function GetAggregateList : TList<T>;
end;

function TNestedList<T>.GetAggregateList : TList<T>;

var
  List : TList<T>;
  Item : T;

begin
  Result := TList<T>.Create;
  for List in Self do
    for Item in List do
      Result.Add(Item);
  end;
```

No need to implement `GetAggregateList` for specific types - that's what you use generics for.

Also note that it might be better to either call your method `CreateAggregateList` (to make clear that the caller is responsible for destroying the created list) or to pass in an already created list instance into a procedure:

```
procedure GetAggregateList(List : TList<T>);
```

...which leaves list ownership completely to the caller and is quite a common pattern in Delphi.

Comment: Thanks, I think this approach will do just fine. I have to do some recursive operations which will be ok in this type of structure.